# Sorting in SQL query in ascending order

Tags: sql-server, sorting

I have a varchar field `CaseNo` in table which contains the data in this format for eg.

```
FA/12/2014,
FA/11/2015, 
FA/12/2015, 
FA/11/2014,  
CC/12/2015,
CC/11/2015
```

I wanted to sort the result of `select` query in the following manner

```
CC/11/2015
CC/12/2015
FA/11/2014
FA/12/2014
FA/11/2015
FA/12/2015
```

Firstly it should sort first two characters in alphabetic order.
And Then the remaining digits in ascending order and result should be like as above..
Note:- last part of the data is year but middle part is not a month it is just a number.
Is this possible to do so.
Thanks

Comment: Let see relative question [here][1], Hope this help!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: thanks that solution is related to spliting the field data but i wanted to sort the data on the basis of parts of the field data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do this :

```
    select * from temp
    order by 
    left(columnA,2) asc ,
    right(columnA,4) asc,      
    cast(replace(replace(columnA,left(columnA,3),''),right(columnA,5),'') as int) asc
```

And a [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d88a4/5) here !
So you edited the post and this should work just fine. This is not converting into Date the last part of the string

Comment: Thanks now first part and last part are sorting good but middle part is still creating problem have a look <br/> following is the result<br/> FA/7/2015
FA/8/2015
FA/9/2015
FA/100/2015
FA/600/2015
FA/500/2015
FA/200/2015
FA/700/2015
FA/701/2015
FA/201/2015
FA/501/2015
FA/601/2015
FA/101/2015
FA/102/2015
FA/602/2015
FA/502/2015
FA/702/2015
FA/202/2015
FA/203/2015
FA/703/2015
FA/503/2015
FA/603/2015
FA/103/2015
FA/104/2015
FA/604/2015
FA/504/2015
FA/204/2015

Comment: Ha sry i didn't knew that the middle number can be bigger then 99

Comment: very near to solution. now getting result as follows FA/1/2014 FA/10/2014 FA/11/2014, FA/19/2014
FA/2/2014
FA/20/2014
FA/21/2014
FA/22/2014
FA/23/2014,
FA/3/2014
FA/4/2014, FA/8/2014
FA/9/2014
FA/1/2015
FA/10/2015
FA/100/2015
FA/101/2015

Comment: Little change (using CAST)in your query make it to work as exactly that i needed following is the solution, <br/> order by 
left(CaseNo_ID,2) asc ,right(CaseNo_ID,4) asc,
CAST(( replace(replace(CaseNo_ID,left(CaseNo_ID,3),''),right(CaseNo_ID,5),'')) as int)  asc

Comment: ok. right. updated the answer. you can mark it as solution now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83959/discussion-between-ankitsrist-and-dzomba).

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
select * from table1 
order by left(col1, 2), convert(date, '01/' + substring(col1, 4, 7), 103)
```

My assumption was that the last part is month + year, but of course it could be something else too.

Comment: thanks actually last part is year but middle part is just a number not month.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `order by`. More generic way

```
ORDER  BY LEFT ('FA/12/2014', Charindex('/', 'FA/12/2014') - 1),
          Cast('01'+ Substring('FA/12/2014', Charindex('/', 'FA/12/2014'), 8) AS DATE)
```

**DEMO**

```
SELECT *
FROM   (VALUES ('CC/11/2015'),
               ('CC/12/2015'),
               ('FA/11/2014'),
               ('FA/12/2014'),
               ('FA/11/2015'),
               ('FA/12/2015')) tc (dates)
ORDER  BY LEFT (dates, Charindex('/', dates) - 1),
          Cast('01'
               + Substring(dates, Charindex('/', dates), 8) AS DATE)
```

Result :

```
dates
----------
CC/11/2015
CC/12/2015
FA/11/2014
FA/12/2014
FA/11/2015
FA/12/2015
```

Comment: why do you chose the most complicated way to do it ?

Comment: @dzomba - No. Its not about complicated its more generic. Tomorrow instead of CC if CCC comes also this will work.

Comment: "Note:- last part of the data is year but middle part is not a month it is just a number." so your answer is not good.

Comment: middle part is not a month but just a number

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use PARSENAME in this case

```
SELECT *
FROM   #Your_Table
ORDER  BY Parsename(Replace(columnA, '/', '.'), 3),
          Parsename(Replace(columnA, '/', '.'), 1),
          Parsename(Replace(columnA, '/', '.'), 2)
```